# Bulk Inserting Into ElasticSearch Index

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using Mongoosastic a mongoose plugin that can automatically index your models into elasticsearch.

Have a requirement of reading data from an excel file and upload the data into MongoDB and simultaneously to ElasticSearch Index.

Everything Works perfectly but, When the data from excel file exceeds more than 200 let's say 300. Data total of 300 objects is inserted into MongoDB but only 200 records are inserted on ElasticSearch index.

To insert this data am using Mongoose InsertMany function, which by defulat triggers elasticsearch cluster as mentioned in the Mongoosastic.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
       question: {
            type: String ,
            required: true,
            text: true,
            index: true,
            es_type:"text",
            es_analyzer: "faq_standard"
        },
        keyword: [{
            type: String ,
            required: false,
            index: true,
            default: [""],
            es_type:"text",es_analyzer: "faq_standard"
        }],
        answer: {
            type: String ,
            required: true,
            text: true,
            es_type:"text", es_analyzer: "faq_standard"
        },
        }
);
schema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: getElasticInstance()
});
```

The above was my model definiton, and used Elasticsearch client instance.

For Inserting the data, I have used InsertMany() function of Mongoose ODM.
Below was my function that has key payload which holds json data.

```
let err, data;
  [err, data]=await to(Faq.insertMany(payload.content));
  if(err) TE(err, true);
  if(data) return data;
```

If the data to be inserted is below 200, then Data is inserted into the ES index. But when the data exceeds only a part of that data was being Inserted Nearly 200-210.

I don't understand where is the exact problem, but any Help is more helpful

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#isMaster.maxWriteBatchSize  check the `maxWriteBatchSize` on the db.. insertMany limits on the basis of this key.

Comment: But the Data is being inserted into MongoDB.While it's not indexing into ElasticSearch Index if bulk insert size of data exceeds more than 300. That leads to 200 documents are on ElasticSearch Cluster, whereas 300 documents on MongoDB. I hope you understood my problem :)

Comment: hey.. i was searching your issue and found that there is no formula to calculate bulk indexing size in ElasticSearch but bulk majorly depend on two things that is Document size and the Hardware resource you have (Heap Size, Ram.. ).  So what is the size of 200 documents that are synced.. try with different sizes..

i hope it helps.. thanks :)